# get the full height of the document, so that when you scroll all the way to the bottom the scrollY value matches the full length of the HTML document

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll, scrollbar, document

I would like to use JS to calculate how far a user scrolled down a page.

I'm trying to use a combination of `scrollY` and `document.body.offsetHeight`

But what I'm finding is that `scrollY` at the bottom of a page is returning `6883` but the `document.body.offsetHeight` is returning a value of `7392` - which leaves me in a place where I can't calculate the how far a user scrolled down the document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

> Typically, offsetHeight is a measurement in pixels of the element's
> CSS height, including any borders, padding, and horizontal scrollbars
> (if rendered). It does not include the height of pseudo-elements such
> as ::before or ::after. For the document body object, the measurement
> includes total linear content height instead of the element's CSS
> height. Floated elements extending below other linear content are
> ignored.

So if I understand this correctly, it's taking into account the document in view of the viewport - so that should return the value of `6883`, the same if a user scrolls the full length of the page.

What property do you use to calculate full scrollable view of a document, to compare to the max value of `scrollY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try using `document.body.offsetHeight-window.innerHeight` it should return the expected scrollable value.

Comment: you know what it had to do with my console open and I think that was messing with it, but this works great, thanks

Comment: This seems to affects only some browsers, the embed console is not taken in consideration for diminishing the window inner height. But I have not met it on my side, one way to avoid it is to use the console in detached mode.